# Upload File with Data from Android App

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-core

I have an Android app, and a .NET Core 2.0 Web API. I would like to upload a picture, together with some data pertaining to the picture (UserID, PIN, etc). Quick googling points me to Microsoft docs which says [you should use the IFormFile interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

I would like to know if there is any way of uploading a file, as well as a json object to describe the picture being uploaded to the API? If not, would I have to create two action methods, one for the picture and the other for the json data? What would the best approach be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367602/upload-files-and-json-in-asp-net-core-web-api?rq=1

Comment: The same doc tells you "IFormFile can be used directly as an action method parameter or as a viewmodel property, as shown above.". So, create a ViewModel with the data you want to pass as JSON

Comment: In Android, you could try making a multipart upload object