# Asp.net core sending form-data and json body at the same to

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to upload a file and also JSON body at the same time to a POST method as below

```
  public async Task<ResponseModel<PersonWriteResponse>> AddPerson([FromForm]IFormFile file, [FromForm]PersonPostRequest request)
        {
            var person = await _service.AddPerson(file,request);
            return ResponseModelHelper.BuildResponse(person, $"/production/person", "person");
        }
```

Both parameters are always null. In postman, I am specifying the content-type as "Multipart/form-data"
Is this the correct way of passing file and json data?

- Alan-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload files and JSON in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367602/upload-files-and-json-in-asp-net-core-web-api)

Answer (score -1):

I try to use model witch include IFormFile, and it's works

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> update([FromForm]MyFile model)
    {
        return Ok("Success!");
    }

    public class MyFile
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }        
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
        // Other properties
    }
```

[PostMan request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igw8A.png) here

You may set breakPoint at the `return Ok("Success!");` line and saw what you get