# Receiving multipart form-data json parameter null

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, multipartform-data, multipart

I am trying to receive a multipart request from `Postman` containg 3 parameters:

- An `int`
- A `file`
- A `Json`

I receive in the controller both the `file` and the `integer` fine, but the json has all the fields as null.
What could be wrong ?

**Json**

```
    [Serializable]
    public class ProcessingRecipe
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("fileId")]
        public string FileID { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("srcLang")]
        public string SrcLang { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route(Routes.Routes.File.PROCESS)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<FileProcessResponse>> ProcessFileAsync([FromForm]IFormFile uploadFile,[FromForm] ProcessingRecipe recipe,[FromForm]int aa)
    {
             //the file is ok
            // the int is 33
    }
```

**Postman**

[image]

**Update** !!!!!

I have used according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367602/upload-files-and-json-in-asp-net-core-web-api) to no avail:

**Custom Binder**

```
public class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        if (bindingContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        // Check the value sent in
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None) {
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

            // Attempt to convert the input value
            var valueAsString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
            var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(valueAsString, bindingContext.ModelType);
            if (result != null) {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**Controller action**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<FileProcessResponse>> ProcessFileAsync([FromForm]IFormFile uploadFile,[ModelBinder(typeof(JsonModelBinder))] ProcessingRecipe recipe)
        {
                 //the file is ok
                // the int is 33
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload files and JSON in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367602/upload-files-and-json-in-asp-net-core-web-api)

Comment: I am not using `Newtonsoft`.

Comment: It doesn't matter here, you can use System.Text.Json but you need to create a custom ModelBinder

Comment: I have used the Custom ModelBinder to no avail.Now i get all the object as `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to upload a file and json data in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037049/how-to-upload-a-file-and-json-data-in-postman)

Comment: I have tried the "duplicate" solutions and they don't work for me...

Comment: I tested your updated code ,and it worked well . [Here](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/EQ99O-p53vtMuq6JAdw4RM0BQl32Ql9Hp1-AM_QmH9l3Ng?e=erDDDZ) is my test demo , you could check the differences .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a definite duplicate of [how to upload a file and json data in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037049/how-to-upload-a-file-and-json-data-in-postman)

In your case, maybe you can try something like what is suggested in the following(https://stackoverflow.com/a/52748531/11226302)

Comment: That is the only way it worked for me.Serializing the json into a string and sending it like a form `input` alongside my file.