# 415 (Unsupported Media Type) when upload file

Tags: c#, .net, postman

I write code to post data from a form with file upload

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<Models.Event> CreateEvent(Models.Event events, IFormFile file)
        {
            string dbPath = null;
            var folderName = Path.Combine("wwwroot");
            var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using var image = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream());
                image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(112, 112));
                var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);
                dbPath = Path.Combine("api/event/items/pic/", fileName);
                image.Save(fullPath);
            }

            events.LogoImageFilePath = dbPath;
            _eventService.CreateEvent(events);
            return Ok(events);
        }
```

This is my model Event

```
public class Event 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LogoImageFilePath { get; set; }
}
```

When I use Postman to post data

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "00-e6310fde4fabb24ca3fd39a897475187-f3154d2024ff8f4f-00"
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.
This is my Postman request
[image: my Postman request]
Headers Tab
[image: Headers Tab]

Comment: What is the value of the "Content-Type" header you send?

Comment: You should also share your Postman request. Otherwise, how can anybody help you?

Comment: I updated image of my Postman request.

Comment: I think you need to decorate the `events` controller parameter with `[FromBody]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload files and JSON in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367602/upload-files-and-json-in-asp-net-core-web-api)

Comment: Can you show "Headers" tab, pls?

Comment: @Sergey I updated image of my Headers tab.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73931284/flutter-return-415-unsupported-media-type-with-http-multipartrequest/73935892#73935892

Answer (score 0):

Add to Event  IFormFile property

```
public class Event 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LogoImageFilePath { get; set; }

     [NotMapped]
    [DisplayName("Upload File")]
    public IFormFile File {get; set;}
}
```

and change your action header:

```
public ActionResult<Models.Event> CreateEvent( [FromBody] Event events)
{
var file=Events.File;
....

}
```