# Flutter: How to send multiple images using for loop

Tags: flutter, api, loops

I am using http package to perform multipart request.I am trying to upload multiple images using for loop but I am not getting any idea how to do it following is my postman response in the below image you can see 2 fields one is attribute and another one is image here I want to loop only adhar and pan inside attributes after sending `"mobileno":"4567654","role":"p","userstatus":"D",` to database
[image]following is my multipart request code

```
Future<void> insertCategory(String category, BuildContext context) async {
var flutterFunctions =
    Provider.of<FlutterFunctions>(context, listen: false);
var data = {"mobileno":"4567654","role":"p","userstatus":"D","adhar":"adhar","pan":"pan"};
var url = PurohitApi().baseUrl + PurohitApi().insertcategory;
Map<String, String> obj = {"attributes": json.encode(data).toString()};
try {
  loading();
  final client = RetryClient(
    http.Client(),
    retries: 4,
    when: (reponse) {
      return reponse.statusCode == 401 ? true : false;
    },
    onRetry: (request, response, retryCount) async {
      if (retryCount == 0 && response?.statusCode == 401) {
        var accesstoken = await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
            .restoreAccessToken();
        request.headers['Authorization'] = accesstoken;
        print(accesstoken);
      }
    },
  );
  var response = await http.MultipartRequest('Post', Uri.parse(url))
    ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
        "imagefile", flutterFunctions.imageFile!.path,
        contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg")))
    ..headers['Authorization'] = token!
    ..fields.addAll(obj);
  final send = await client.send(response);
  final res = await http.Response.fromStream(send);
  var messages = json.decode(res.body);
  loading();
  print(messages);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73931284/flutter-return-415-unsupported-media-type-with-http-multipartrequest/73935892#73935892

Comment: in your answer there is no for loop not related to this question

Answer (score 0):

```
 Future<Object> addUserImages(List<XFile> files, String userID, String token) async {
    try {
      var url = Uri.parse(API_BASE_URL + addUserImagesUrl);

      var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);

      request.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer ${StaticServices.userBaseModel!.token!.token}";

      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        String fileName = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString().characters.takeLast(7).toString();
        var pic = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes("files", await File(files[i].path).readAsBytes(), filename: '${userID}_${i}_$fileName', contentType: MediaType("image", files[i].mimeType ?? "png"));

        //add multipart to request
        request.files.add(pic);
      }

      var response = await request.send();
      var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
      var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return Success(response: Images.fromJson(jsonDecode(responseString)));
      }
      return Failure(
        errorMessage: responseString,
      );
    } on HttpException {
      return Failure(errorMessage: "No Internet Connection");
    } on FormatException {
      return Failure(errorMessage: "Invalid Format");
    } on SocketException {
      return Failure(errorMessage: "No Internet Connection");
    } catch (e) {
      return Failure(errorMessage: "Invalid Error");
    }
  }
```

Comment: thx for reply but in question I had clearly mentioned that I want to loop only particular data not to loop all fields when sending multi part request

Comment: Not all fields are in the loop, it just has a loop that will loop for how many images you have

Comment: ok in your answer your just adding files but if I want to add fields also then??

Comment: once see my post man  image  there are fields and files both are in multipart request but I need only files to be looped but not fields in request...I need to send fields and files both using request