# Unable to send a Multipart request with an Image and JSON using [FromForm]

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a controller endpoint that I want to use for both uploading an image, and also sending a JSON payload.

I know in Spring boot you could use @RequestPart annotation and pass the key/value pair as form data. I'm using .net core but struggling to test sending a request to my endpoint.

My model class looks like this:
**CreateCompanyRequest.cs**

```c
public class CreateCompanyRequest {
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public CreateAddressRequest? Address { get; set; }
    public int IndustryId { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public DateTime FoundedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And I also have a wrapper class that contains this Request class, along with an IFormFile property to use for uploading a file.

**CreateCompanyMultipartRequest.cs**

```cs
public class CreateCompanyMultipartRequest {
    
    [FromForm(Name = "company")]
    public CreateCompanyRequest Company { get; set; }
    
    [FromForm(Name = "avatar")]
    public IFormFile Avatar { get; set; }
}
```

**CompanyController.cs**

```cs
     [Authorize(Roles = "Recruiter")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCompany([FromForm] CreateCompanyMultipartRequest request) {
            
            var response = await _companyService.CreateCompany(request.Company, "john@gmail.com");
            
            if (response != null && request.Avatar != null) {
                await _documentService.UploadDocument(request.Avatar, DocumentType.AVATAR, "john@gmail.com", response.Id);
            }
            
           // Extra validation..

            return Ok(new ApiResponse<CompanyResponse>() {
                Data = response, Status = true
            });
        }
```

I tried sending the request in postman with the keys being **Avatar** and **Company**, which match the request class, but I get this validation error.

The data im sending for the Company is a json file with the required properties, also tried sending the json as a text type in Postman.

[image]

Comment: have you tried using 'company' as key instead of 'Company'?

Comment: Yep, i tried different casing for the keys. Still the same

Comment: i dont know the solution but if I were debugging this I would try to keep the model flat i.e. list props of CreateCompanyRequest in CreateCompanyMultipartRequest and see if that works... my suspicion currently is that when you say FromForm, may be simple data type is expected.. but just a guess at this point

Comment: is there a reason for passing a .json file instead of json content? does it work if you send {'name': 'a', 'description':'d'...} for company instead?

Comment: I'll try what you suggested @haku. There's no reason for sending a json file, It gave the same validation message when passing the json body directly

Comment: Better to send as a FormData object.  (Maybe include your front-end code?)

Comment: @pcalkins I haven't done the frontend for the upload yet, but I'm assuming I can still use a form data object when making the request to my api. (For the JSON body and the image)

Comment: yes, but FormData will make key/value pairs.  It will no longer be JSON.  Easiest way is to just build the FormData() object passing in the form element client-side.  But you can also append key/value pairs.  You can send it all as JSON if you like and use FromBody, but the file would be have to be Base64 methinks...  that's going to be inefficient for file transfers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try post with json string and then deserialize to object in controller.

```
    public class CreateCompanyMultipartRequest
    {
        public string Company { get; set; }

        public IFormFile Avatar { get; set; }
    }
```

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCompany([FromForm]CreateCompanyMultipartRequest request)
        {
            CreateCompanyRequest createCompanyRequest =JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CreateCompanyRequest>(request.Company);
            .....
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you require is currently not supported by ASP.NET Core. The `[FromForm]` does not reflect the nested content types in multi-part content, it basically assumes form data all the way. I'd say the thinking is based on supporting HTML forms and not much else as multi-part contents seem rarer outside of MVC use-case. The limitation is tracked by issue [#4868](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4868) so please consider upvoting if this is important to you.

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41367602/3593970) was already raised on Stack Overflow and it has additional solutions. Needless to say, [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77719885/3593970) by Qiang Fu should also work as a starting point.

I'd add that the either the signature needs to be as follows or the request needs to incorporate the `request` parameter name for reasons based in ASP.NET Core binding philosophy.

So the method would be

```cs
public IActionResult CreateCompany([FromForm] string company, [FromForm] IFormFile avatar)
```

Or the request would be

```
POST /test/companies HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.3
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:5101
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------028802399612703935732606
Content-Length: 5971
 
----------------------------028802399612703935732606
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="request.company"
{ "name": "Dummy Name", "description": "Dummy Description" }
----------------------------028802399612703935732606
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="request.avatar"; filename="img.jpg"
<img.jpg>
----------------------------028802399612703935732606--
```

[image: Screenshot of Postman UI with the request above]

---

That being said, if you control the client and passing the data in form format would be OK for you, you might as well do it like ASP.NET Core wants.

C#:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("companies")]
    public IActionResult CreateCompany([FromForm] CreateCompanyMultipartRequest request)
    {
        return Ok($"Received company Name='{request.Company.Name}', Description='{request.Company.Description}'; avatar File='{request.Avatar.FileName}', Length={request.Avatar.Length}");
    }
}

public class CreateCompanyMultipartRequest
{
    [FromForm(Name = "company")]
    public CreateCompanyRequest Company { get; set; }

    [FromForm(Name = "avatar")]
    public IFormFile Avatar { get; set; }
}

public class CreateCompanyRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public object? Address { get; set; }
    public int IndustryId { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public DateTime FoundedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Example request from Postman

```
POST /test/companies HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.3
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:5101
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------424326738567053882838060
Content-Length: 6069
 
----------------------------424326738567053882838060
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="request.company.name"
Dummy Name
----------------------------424326738567053882838060
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="request.company.description"
Dummy Description
----------------------------424326738567053882838060
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="request.avatar"; filename="img.jpg"
<img.jpg>
----------------------------424326738567053882838060--
```

and response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 27 Dec 2023 11:48:28 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 
Received company Name='Dummy Name', Description='Dummy Description'; avatar File='img.jpg', Length=5582
```

[image: Screenshot of Postman UI with the preceding request and response]

---

Personally, I'd rather go with the manual deserialization and possibly mess a bit with binders if this was the case for significant number of APIs.

Comment: Thank you, I went with the manual deserialization and it works. No I'm having an issue with EF core tracking lol.